# Find symbol address of Mach-o from mach_header in memory

Tags: c, mach-o, xnu

I have a mach-o file loaded in memory (via `mmap`) and need to get the address in the binary corresponding to a symbol, say `mySym`. I found a function called `NSLookupSymbolInImage` and thought I could use that and then use `NSAddressOfSymbol` to get the actual address, but there are some issues with that:

- These functions are deprecated
- While looking at the source of `NSLookupSymbolInImage`, it appears that the `mach_header` passed in must already be loaded by dyld. Since I loaded the binary myself, this method probably won't work.

Now, I know that if I must, I can parse the `mach_header` myself and find the symbol that way, but I would like to think that there is an better way of doing this.

Basically, I want to know if there is an easier method to get the address of a symbol from a mach-o file not loaded by dyld than doing it manually.

Comment: [this](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump/blob/master/Source/CDMachOFile.h) might be of some use.